# Is this the correct way to use a inheritence?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if these types of questions aren't allowed.

I have a simple base for something similar to plugins.
Here's my example

```
class Plugin{
    private bool _Enabled;
    public bool Enabled{
        get{
            return _Enabled;
        }
        set{
            _Enabled = value;
            if(value)
                MyExecutionHandler += Run;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Run(object source, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        if(!Enabled)
            return;
    }
}
```

Now currently I'm doing something like this:

```
class CustomPlugin : Plugin{
    public override void Run(object source, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        base.Run(source, args);
    }
}
```

First of all is the logic behind this correct?

Secondly can I force them to implement the Run function from the partial class or do I need to create an interface for that?

Comment: what is the use of keyword `partial` ? you know that it is used to split a single class in multiple source file?

Comment: @Gerritlest, check out this site and get a quick understanding of [Partial Class](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0140__Class/Defineandusepartialclass.htm) also read up about what is `Inheritance` and `OOP Tutorials`

Comment: What your code "describes" is inheritance, where you generally define a base set of functionality in a class or interface (`Plugin`). Then your child class either inherits from that parent class, or implements that interface and expands upon that "base" functionality that all plugins will have, while adding whatever `CustomPlugin`'s functionality is. As @Habib described, `partial` is simply for breaking up a single class across multiple files. The easiest example is creating a WinForms application, your `Form.cs` and `Form.designer.cs` are the same class, split across 2 files using `partial`

Comment: [Read more on the `partial` keyword here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). It even describes common usages of `partial`.

Comment: @Habib apparently I've fully misunderstood the meaning of partial.


So making it a normal class is correct usage? Is there anything prevent it from being used as a normal class? you're not supposed to instantiate it on it's own. Is there anything to prevent that

Comment: @GerritIest The keyword you're looking for is [`abstract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx). An abstract class cannot be instantiated but can be inherited.

Comment: @NateBarbettini Thanks, but as the answer below says abstact methods can't define "default" behaviour like I want to do. So although it seems to be what I was looking for (with the intention of partial) it isn't what I'm looking after all

Comment: @GerritIest You can have "default" behavior in an abstract class, using a `virtual` method. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an `abstract` class with "default" behavior by declaring a method as `virtual` and overriding it in derived classes.

A derived class is not forced to override a `virtual` method in an abstract base class. If the method is not overridden, the behavior defined in the abstract class is used. Overriding the method can be used to replace the behavior entirely, or implement additional functionality (on top of calling `base.MethodName()`).

Unless I've misunderstood your question, this pattern should work for your scenario.

---

dotnetfiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JQQ6I

Abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Plugin
{
    public virtual string Output()
    {
        return "Default";
    }
}
```

A derived class that uses the default implementation, and one that overrides it:

```
public class BoringPlugin : Plugin 
{
    public override string Output()
    {
        return base.Output();
    }
}

public class ExcitingPlugin : Plugin
{
    public override string Output()
    {
        return "No boring defaults here!";
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var boring = new BoringPlugin();
    Console.WriteLine(boring.Output());

    var exciting = new ExcitingPlugin();
    Console.WriteLine(exciting.Output());
}
```

> Default
>
> No boring defaults here!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to use the `partial` keyword.  The `partial` keyword merely allows you to spread the definition of a class into multiple source files.  It isn't something you use to describe the architecture of your program.  You would use it to split the definition into multiple files, something like this:

Plugin1.cs

```
partial class Plugin{
    private bool _Enabled;
    public bool Enabled{
        get{
            return _Enabled;
        }
        set{
            _Enabled = value;
            if(value)
                MyExecutionHandler += Run;
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin2.cs

```
partial class Plugin {
    public virtual void Run(object source, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        if(!Enabled)
            return;
    }
}
```

But this isn't helpful to you, and you should forget about the partial keyword (for now).  You seem to be struggling with concepts related to object-oriented programming.  The partial keyword has nothing to do with that, so don't worry about it.

If you want classes which inherit from `Plugin` to be 'forced' to implement the `Run` method, you should use an [abstract method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx).  HOWEVER, as you will read in that link, if you use an abstract method, you will not be able to define the 'default' behavior which you are currently defining in the body of the run method.

If you want classes which inherit from Plugin to be forced to define ADDITIONAL behavior, you can't really do that easily just using concepts like abstract classes / methods / interfaces.  You will find it easier to compromise, and allow classes which inherit from plugin to 'just' have the default behavior of the `Run`  method as described in your `Plugin` base class.

You will probably find this compromise acceptable.  I think you will find that forcing classes which inherit from `Plugin` to do additional things in the `Run` method doesn't buy you anything.  The behavior in the base `Run` method should still be considered a 'correct', if minimal / useless 'Run' of any type of  derived `Plugin`.

I can't speak to the logic of your program, it isn't clear what you intend for these Plugins to do, but hopefully this will help you figure out exactly what you want to do, and how to do it.

Comment: I mainly struggled with the use / meaning of partial. I though it could be used to notify it's not a full class and requires more. My mistake. I'll just keep it a regular class then and won't force it. What I don't understand why I get downvoted for wrong knowledge. Thought this place is for helping people and not shoving them down more.

Comment: People may have down-voted you because it appeared to them like you didn't try to look up information about `partial` in the documentation before you asked this question.  Don't get discouraged, because they may have just misinterpreted you.  If you use resources that people mentioned in the comments on your question (like MSDN) to help describe to people exactly what you are confused about, and mention in your question what resources you consulted while researching your question, you can avoid misunderstandings in the future.

Comment: @GerritIest Btw, you can also upvote answers in addition to accepting them. :)

Comment: @NateBarbettini Combined with the -5 I got due to this question I don't have enough reputation to do so unfortunately